# Managing schema changes with headless CMS content editing

Tags: directus, headless-cms

I work on an application involving user interaction with content-heavy domain entities. I'm exploring using a headless CMS for managing content editing within our product team. I'm looking specifically at Directus as it promises to simply "wrap" the application database. In a world where the domain model doesn't change, content editors work against the production database and the CMS workflow features manage "releases" of content, i.e. by setting pre-release drafts to Published.
Application behavior changes, however, may include breaking changes to schema. Content editing on modified domain entities prior to the release of the new features requires deploying the schema changes to a pre-release database. All content editing now has to occur there and the content has to somehow be shipped upon release over to a migrated production database.
Wondering if there are some good practices for handling this.